# cURL and PHP issue

Tags: php, linux, curl

So far I want a curl command to download a file into a specific directory , So I have done this

```
system('curl -o hi.txt www.site.com/hi.html');
```

It doesn't work because my directory isn't writable , I need to find a way to set curl to download that file to a writable directory of mine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of curl you could use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.site.com/hi.html');
file_put_contents('/htdocs/mysite/images/hi.txt', $file);
```

This method will work even if the curl module isn't installed. To do this using cURL (which will allow more control over the actual http request):

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.site.com/hi.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$out = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

// Save the file
$fp = fopen('/htdocs/mysite/images/hi.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $out);
fclose($fp);
```

#### EDIT

```
system('curl -o /htdocs/mysite/images/hi.txt www.site.com/hi.html');
```

Comment: It didn't work for me , Note my public_html isn't writable , So that's why I want to download a file to any other writable directory

Comment: well simply change the path to the writable directory

Comment: what directory is writable under public_html?

Comment: /htdocs/mysite/images     // The images directory is writable

Comment: I edited my post to reflect your writable directory and also added an example using your `system()` call